# Can SU group be used on Suse as it is AIX?

Tags: su, suse, aix

I'm the admin of a large AIX environment. I utilize the SU Group attribute for users to determine who can access root, even if they know the password. If they are not in the root group then access is denied.

Is there a similar function in Suse?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not know and haven't seen that kind of function of linux.

However, AIX's brain is somewhat split when switching user context is in question. There is the **chuser sugroups=** (or smitty in the appropriate menu) mechanism that ships with the OS, but the possibilities of **sudo**  are also exploitable. If any user elevated to root starts using both, it may make difficult to guess who's who and who can be who. Since we must use sudo anyway, we simply forgot chuser sugroups to have all grants in one file.

The group-based sudo commands is what linux basically uses, although nothing stops distributors to reinvent the wheel (and the wheel group) and come out with a solution just to be misfit. I would not follow them even if they kindly offered me the red pill.